# Aspnet core ZKTECO device

Tags: connection

how to connect  ZKT ECo To Aspnetcore or mvc

i try to connect that device to aspnetcore but con not
for this we want to show me and help me in this the case  i searched many many time but we con not find some thing in this context

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.